# Telerik asp.net ajax Cargar Combobox en Cascada sin PostBack

Tags: ajax, asp.net, combobox, telerik

Buenos días!
Estoy utilizando los controles de telerik y me gustaría saber si hay alguna posibilidad de poder cargar un combobox en cascada sin tener el efecto de postback, me explico, no quiero que se vea el efecto de recargar el formulario ya que queda muy feo visualmente.

He intentado utilizar la funcionalidad de llamar a los métodos mediatamente ajax pero cuando cargo los valores del combobox 2 no se ven en pantalla por tanto no me carga el combobox 2.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer esto.

Muchas Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, considera ampliar tu respuesta aportando un ejemplo mínimo (a ser posible compilable) que reproduzca el problema (no pongas capturas de pantalla). Tal cual está elaborada tu pregunta puede ser complicado que te proporcionemos respuestas concretas.

Answer (score 0):

En los controles DevXpress se usan Callbacks para hacer eso sin hacer PostBack. Pero en telerik aqui hay unas demos tambien, a ver si te valen

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Además siempre puedes usar un UpdatePanel para evitar los Postback, aqui tienes mas info https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: De hecho en telerik el homologo de UpdatePanel es RadAjaxManager, sería mejor si usas ese.